# How come "chulada" in Spain is almost an antonym from it's meaning in Guatemala and Mexico?

Tags: definiciones, etimología

I just find utterly curious that [chulada](http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/definicion.php?palabra=chulada) has almost opposite meanings depending on the country.

> *chulada. (De chulo).*
>
> 1. f. Acción indecorosa, propia de gente de mala educación o ruin condición.
>
>    ...
> 2. f. Guat. y Méx. Belleza de las personas.

I've tried to find out an evolution process for this word, but I haven't been succesful. Has somebody an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to say that I'm really surprised about the first definition of `chulada` you included, I had never heard it with that meaning... I may use `chulería` with that sense...

Obviously it should be correct because it's in the dicionary, but I'd only use the word `chulada` with the meaning of the second definition in the dictionary -which you omitted-:

> *Dicho o hecho gracioso con cierta soltura y desenfado.*

And in this case, the meanings in Spain and in Guatemala and México seem to be much more similar, don't they?

Comment: En el significado #1. Yo creo como dice en diccionario `chulada` cuando el contexto es sobre `chulo` aunque no es muy comun usarlo, pero puede darse el caso

Answer (score 3):

We have to search the answer in the original word: *chulo*. In Spain we have to basic meanings:

1) (adj.) cool, nice (thing),

2) (adj. normally used as a noun) arrogant, conceited (person)

Thus, the apparently opposite meanings of the word *chulada* seem to have a reasonable origin, and it's another matter to find the origin of the meanings of *chulo*.

Nevertheless, I would rather use *chulería* than *chulada* (for the "bad" meaning).

---

Tenemos que buscar la respuesta en la palabra original: *chulo*. En España tenemos dos significados básicos:

1)(adj.) guay, lindo (objeto),

2)(adj. normalmente sustantivado) arrogante, prepotente (persona).

Así, la aparente contradicción entre los significados de la palabra *chulada* parece tener un origen razonable, y es otra cuestión encontrar el origen de los significados de *chulo*.

Sin embargo, yo usaría *chulería* antes que *chulada* (para el significado "malo").

Answer (score 0):

I've heard the word "Chulo" refering someone as a "Pimp", so it could be used as a bad word.

But the word "Chulada" is always used to say something is really amazing or beautiful.